# Pre-Clone task in mercurial when cloning

Tags: git, clone, mercurial, hg, copy

May I know if we can add a script or some hg-related file in our repository so that when that branch is being cloned it should execute a task. In my case I need to take some files from git repository when I clone my hg project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to achieve this with [mercurial subrepository](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository). 
With the help of .hgsub file, I am able to clone other repository when I clone the main repository. Wit the help of .hgsubstate file, it will track the changes in the sub repository and when we commit and push from main repository, it does the same for sub repository